# How to group by Pandas dataframe based on date and leave specific dates as NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':["2021-10-24", "2021-10-17", "2021-10-31", "2021-11-04", "2021-11-15"],
             'code': ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
              'value':[90, 40, 80, 98, 50]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace = True)
```

And I would like to group values monthly but only filling in values for the earliest date. For the rest of the months I would like to fill values with NaN.

With simply group by:

```
df.groupby(['code']).resample('m').mean()
```

Im getting:

```
               value
code    date    
A   2021-10-31  65.0
B   2021-10-31  80.0
    2021-11-30  74.0
```

And the desired output is :

```
               value
code    date    
A   2021-10-31  65.0
B   2021-10-31  80.0
    2021-11-30  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and set values by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['code']).resample('m').mean()
    
df['value'] = df['value'].mask(df.index.get_level_values('code').duplicated())
print (df)
                value
code date             
A    2021-10-31   65.0
B    2021-10-31   80.0
     2021-11-30    NaN
```